# Why is this apply() custom function is slower in Polars than in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars, pandas-apply

I ran the following in a Jupyter Notebook and was disappointed that similar Pandas code is faster. Hoping someone can show a smarter approach in Polars.

POLARS VERSION

```
def cleanse_text(sentence):
    RIGHT_QUOTE = r"(\u2019)"
    sentence = re.sub(RIGHT_QUOTE, "'", sentence)
    sentence = re.sub(r" +", " ", sentence)
    return sentence.strip()
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("text").apply(lambda x: cleanse_text(x)).keep_name())
```

PANDAS VERSION

```
def cleanse_text(sentence):
    RIGHT_QUOTE = r"(\u2019)"
    sentence = re.sub(RIGHT_QUOTE, "'", sentence)    
    sentence = re.sub(r" +", " ", sentence)
    return sentence.strip() 
df["text"] = df["text"].apply(lambda x: cleanse_text(x))
```

The above Pandas version was 10% faster than the Polars version when I ran this on a dataframe with 750,000 rows of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of combining [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), you can chain 2 instances of [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) in this case, and finally add [`Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html). This will be faster generally (see end of answer as to why), but particularly for `polars`.

**Pandas version**

```
import pandas as pd
t = "'Hello  World\u2019 "
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': [t]*750000})

df['text'] = (df['text']
              .str.replace('\u2019',"'", regex=True)
              .str.replace(' +',' ', regex=True)
              .str.strip())

df.head()

            text
0  'Hello World'
1  'Hello World'
2  'Hello World'
3  'Hello World'
4  'Hello World'
```

**Polars version**

```
import polars as pl
t = "'Hello  World\u2019 "
df_pl = pl.DataFrame({'text': [t]*750000})

df_pl = (df_pl
         .with_column(pl.col('text')
                      .str.replace('\u2019',"'")
                      .str.replace(' +',' ')
                      .str.strip()))

df_pl.head()

┌───────────────┐
│ text          │
│ ---           │
│ str           │
╞═══════════════╡
│ 'Hello World' │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 'Hello World' │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 'Hello World' │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 'Hello World' │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 'Hello World' │
└───────────────┘
```

**Performance comparison**

Results of `timeit` test for each method (`dfs` checked for equality):

```
       method  timeit (s)      perc
0  pandas_new    1.092429  1.000000
1  pandas_old    1.553892  1.422419
2  polars_new    0.151107  0.138322
3  polars_old    1.851840  1.695158
```

As you can see, both new methods for `pandas` and `polars` are faster than the original methods, and the `polars` method is a clear winner, taking only 13.8% of the new `pandas` method.

So, why is `Series.str.replace` (or: `str.strip`) so much faster than `Series.apply`? The reason has to do with the fact that the former performs an operator on an entire Series (e.g. a "column") all at once ("vectorization"), while the latter calls a Python function for each element in the Series separately. E.g. `lambda x: cleanse_text(x)` means: apply a `UDF` (user-defined function) to 1st element in column, 2nd element in column, etc. On larger sets, this will make a huge difference. Cf. also the [documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.apply.html) for `pl.DataFrame.apply`.

Comment: That worked and much appreciated.  However it's still unclear to me exactly why the use of str.replace() is so much faster than apply().  I would expect apply() to run in parallel just as replace() appears to.

Comment: You're welcome. Added some lines at the end on the reason why `Series.str.replace` is so much faster. Hope that adds some clarity.

Comment: @Biosopher apply doesn't automatically run in parallel.  When you use apply, it sends the  calculations back to python which is nearly equivalent to just running a for loop.  When you use expressions then the Rust optimizations, including parallelization (for multiple column operations) kick in.